# Joining MDF shelf to extend length of spare pieces

Tags: mdf, shelf

I have some spare MDF Bullnose Shelving that are 39" combined. I need to build a 32" shelf in a closet space. I will use MDF cleats to support the shelf. Is it possible to combine these for building the closet shelf?

I don't have a biscuit tool. I have a handheld router (if that helps). I think I could use a support bracket in the middle (made with MDF), but I do not like this option because it would consume space that could be used for storage.

Please advise!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to add substantial rigidity and strength via dowels or other means of connection. It's not a material that tolerates bending stress well. The effort to do it properly probably isn't worth the cost of a new 6' or 8' shelf board.

If you were to precisely drill for say six 1/4" x 4" hardwood dowels and liberally apply wood glue to everything it would probably hold fairly well.

Otherwise you need to support it either with a bracket at the joint or lengthwise rails of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother to try to join MDF at all in a straight line as not the strongest material around, however if in a cupboard you could support the underside with a bracket and that would work well for you so not to waste your shelves.